# Can I apply again after getting an Australia tourist visa refusal?

Tags: visa-refusals, australia, tourist-visas, applications

Can I apply again after getting an Australia tourist visa refusal?

The reason for refusal is:

> I have considered the support provided by their parents in India and inviter in Australia. While letters of support and guarantees offered by friends, business associates, or relatives in India or Australia are important in assisting the decision-maker to consider the merits of each case, they are not in themselves sufficient evidence of a genuine visit. The onus is on the applicant to demonstrate their own circumstances and incentives to depart Australia at the end of their trip. After considering the information provided, I am not satisfied that the applicant genuinely intends to stay temporarily in Australia for the purposes set out above.

Comment: Sure. It's not illegal. However doing the same application again will just result in the same outcome. You need to understand why you were refused and address that reason.

Comment: Thank you for your advice

Comment: I think don't waste your time applying again. The ideal application would be is where you provide your documents with valid finances and etc. Who is sponsoring you from Australia ? @gurisingh

Comment: @gurisingh perhaps provide more detail to your case where did you apply from and some more relevant information about your case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This advice would help me a lot. Actually except documents of my employment and funds both into mine & parents accounts, my agent forgot to mention our property documents which is more than our funds. *Could this mistake be a reason of not proving strong ties? * If I don't wanna marry now, can I not get visa in Canada or Australia as a tourist visa. * What should I mention for strong ties? * Actually in this case, my friend sent me invitation for visiting Australia, should I apply again without invitation? Why * What documents should I attach for strong files?

Comment: @gurisingh Why are you using an agent to apply? What prior travel history do you have? A record showing you’ve visited other countries and abided by their immigration rules might help. If your profile is ‘young, single, no/little prior travel history’, you are highly likely to get refused again if you reapply. Property documents don’t necessarily count for much if you don’t meet other criteria. Even less if your job is considered portable and/or could be done remotely. Is your friend an Australian citizen/resident? How would you explain the change of plan if you reapply without an invitation?

Answer (score 4):

You can apply again but with the same information on the forms you will most likely get the same outcome.

The main difference we can see is that now you have a rejected visa application to your name which makes it more likely that the visa officials refuse this one if they see anything wrong or doubtful.

On this site we usually advice to only apply again if your first application had easy to solve mistakes like forgetting to add your bank statements, and even then you have to be sure that this was the only thing wrong.

Better wait till your situation has changed significantly, like better ties to your home country, a more stable job or a family of your own. (This is assuming that your application was refused on some of the more common grounds, if you edit the question with more information we can give better advice.)

--

Added after the addition of details to the question:

This is a case of the immigration officer not believing that you will leave Australia at the end of your planned stay. Which is a rather common reason and one that is very hard to overcome.
Applying again will not help you, unless you forgot to add information.
If/when you have a stable job which earns you more money than you can make in Australia and have additional reasons to return home, like a house you own or a spouse and child, you can apply again.

It is not fair but it is what rich countries have learned is needed to keep out some people who would immigratie illegally. Far more honest people are kept out as well.

---

Proof of property is likely not enough to overcome the officer reluctance to give you the visa.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. The reason of the refusal is as below

Comment: When an embassy states that they are not sure if you leave their country after visa time. You are now left with guess work perhaps your best shot is to read their legal code where you will realise that there are so many things in a visa decision which are vague like "They dont consider Brother or cousin as a close relative who is sponsoring you" Hence visa rejection for the above reason.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the reason for the refusal you mentioned, it seems like the main concern was proving you have strong ties to return to India after your trip. With a refusal, it may be harder to get another visa approved soon. Some things that could help if you reapply would be showing evidence you have a stable job or business in India, own property there, or have family responsibilities to return to.

Just be prepared to demonstrate your intent to abide by the visa conditions. After some time has passed from the refusal, your chances may be better too.